# Social framework not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I am using Xcode 4.5.1 but I couldn't find the Social framework under Link binary with libraries, its strange Any idea, Please help

Comment: i am using xcode 4.5.2 i have it...can you let us know which sdk are you using?

Comment: did you try searching for Social.framework in the search bar provided? you may have missed it by accident. Using xcode 4.5.2 may also solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Review your version of sdk, it might be older.

For `Social.framework` you must be having installed iOS 6.0 minimum on your XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my Xcode to the latest 4.6 Solved the problem. Thanks all.